# Error message when trying to select “top tags”

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

When trying to edit my “top tags” on my Developer Story, I get the following error message when trying to save my selection:

> "too many ignored tags"

Unfortunately it’s not clear (a) what this message refers to, (b) how many is too many, (c) or how to fix it. Here’s a screenshot:

[image]

I’ve tagged this as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) even though it might be intentional, because the UX is completely non-actionable: I have no idea how to save my selection (and it took a nontrivial amount of time, given how many tags there are … incidentally, this UI could use a cleanup).

I tried removing tags from “tech you prefer not to work with” (even though that worked before), to no avail. Maybe the error message refers to the “top tags”? If so this is doubly a bug because my list of top tags is already way too long (and filled with mostly irrelevant tags, see scrollbar size in screenshot) as it stands, I *definitely* don’t want to remove fewer tags.

Comment: "too many ignored tags" -> not only is that a bug, it is a huge lie. There can never be too many ignored tags.

Comment: Could this somehow be related to the SQL server limit of 2100 parameters?

Comment: I wonder what the other 2098 parameters are then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now fixed. And congrats on having so many top tags.